# PHP get dates between two dates not working as expected

Tags: php, date, period

I am trying to get all dates between two dates using **DatePeriod** class. Its working fine when the dates inputed are of the same month, but not returning all dates when the two dates are of different months.

If the dates are say **2013-06-27** and **2013-07-05** its only returning **2013-06-27, 2013-06-28, 2013-06-29, 2013-06-30**. Its not giving the rest of the dates.

### CODE

```
 $begin = new DateTime($start);
 $last = new DateTime($end);
 $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
 $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $last);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behavior

```
<?php
$start = '2013-06-27';
$end = '2013-07-05';

$begin = new DateTime($start);
$last = new DateTime($end);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $last, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

echo 'phpversion: ', phpversion(), "\n";

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
    echo $dt->format("l Y-m-d H:i:s"), "\n";
}
echo "done.\n";
```

prints

```
phpversion: 5.4.7
Friday 2013-06-28 00:00:00
Saturday 2013-06-29 00:00:00
Sunday 2013-06-30 00:00:00
Monday 2013-07-01 00:00:00
Tuesday 2013-07-02 00:00:00
Wednesday 2013-07-03 00:00:00
Thursday 2013-07-04 00:00:00
done.
```

Which version of php do you use?

Comment: phpversion: 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2

Comment: That's ubuntu 12.10 (QuantalQuetzal)?